# Arch Linux "poweroff" always waits 90 seconds in VMware Player

Tags: linux, vmware, arch-linux, reboot, systemctl

I am running Arch Linux (installed from `archlinux-2014.01.05-dual.iso`) on VMware Player and have installed `vmtoolsd` (which belongs to `open-vm-tools`).

Now my problem is that, whenever I do `poweroff` or `reboot`, the system just leaves me with a black screen with only a cursor flashing at the top-left corner. If I don't do anything to it, the system will shutdown or reboot in one or two minutes.

I've searched Google for this problem. Some people suggest that I modify `/usr/lib/systemd/system/vmtoolsd.service` and that I add one line for `KillSignal=SIGKILL` or `TimeoutStopSec=2`. However, none of these works. Actually when I do `systemctl stop vmtoolsd`, it seems to stop quickly.

I guess maybe some other service is in the similar state as is discussed in those posts I see. Is there a workaround on this so that I can shutdown my virtual machine immediately and gracefully, or that I can figure out what is going on during `poweroff` is executing so that I can tell if any service is blocked?

Update March 4, 2014: I reinstalled Arch Linux and the problem is still there! Is that an issue of VMware? I use VMware Player 6 for Linux? How to display the details when the system is shutting down so that I may know where it gets stuck?

Update March 4, 2014: I used Arch Linux Live CD and similar problem happens with error message: **A stop job is running for User Manager for 0**. Then I thought this might be a bug which is reported here: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=70593 which is a bug of `systemd` and was fixed in update 209 or 210. I then did an update using `pacman -Syu` and the delay was gone. However, I think I have updated my Arch Linux last time when I have `open-vm-tools` installed (before I reinstall the entire system). Now I plan to install `open-vm-tools` again and see if the same error occurs.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using `open-vm-tools`? If not, get rid of it. Features like mouse integration don't depend on it.

Comment: I just reinstalled my Arch Linux but it seems the problem continues. Does it mean that the problem belongs to VMware Player instead of `vmtoolsd`?

Comment: @DanielB I updated my question to reflect the progress on the issue. I think it may due to another bug which is caused by `systemd`. As is reported, `vmtoolsd` may also cause similar phenomenon. I didn't figure out what really happened to me yet. Thanks for your suggestion.